# Does anyone have a formula for Worldedit to create an icosahedron?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I'm searching for a formula for an icosahedron (a polyhedron with 20 faces) to use for Worldedit.
I searched a lot but couldn't find an icosahedron formula for Minecraft that I could use for building.

Comment: What's an Ikosaeder?

Comment: Through some research, it seems like "ikosaeder" is german for "icosahedron" - a polyhedron with 20 faces. I made an edit that changed ikosaeder to icosahedron to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer moved from body of question

---

After more research i found something that could solve this problem
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosahedralEquation.html